# Multipart form upload of binary file using casperjs outside of state machine (can't use fill)

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, telegram-bot

UPDATE 1: I've created a GIST with actual running code in a test jig to show exactly what I'm running up against.  I've included working bot tokens (to a throw-away bot) and access to a telegram chat that the bot is already in, in case anyone wants to take a quick peek.  It's

https://gist.github.com/pleasantone/59efe5f9d7f0bf1259afa0c1ae5a05fe

---

UPDATE 2: I've looked at the following articles for answers already (and a ton more):

https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata/blob/master/formdata.js

[PhantomJS - Upload a file without submitting a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447967/phantomjs-upload-a-file-without-submitting-a-form)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/CHq3ZndjV0k

[How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

[How to create a File object from binary data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283772/how-to-create-a-file-object-from-binary-data-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

I've got a program written in casperjs (phantomjs) that successfully sends messages to Telegram via the BOT API, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to send up a photo.

I can access my photo either as a file, off the local filesystem, or I've already got it as a base64 encoded string (it's a casper screen capture).

I know my photo is good, because I can post it via CURL using:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto" -F chat_id=<id> -F photo=@/tmp/photo.png
```

I know my code for connecting to the bot api from within capserjs is working, as I can do a sendMessage, just not a sendPhoto.

```
function sendMultipartResponse(url, params) {
    var boundary = '-------------------' + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 8));
    var content = [];

    for (var index in params) {
        content.push('--' + boundary + '\r\n');
        var mimeHeader = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + index + '";';
        if (params[index].filename)
            mimeHeader += ' filename="' + params[index].filename + '";';
        content.push(mimeHeader + '\r\n');
        if (params[index].type)
            content.push('Content-Type: ' + params[index].type + '\r\n');
        var data = params[index].content || params[index];
//        if (data.length !== undefined)
//            content.push('Content-Length: ' + data.length + '\r\n');
        content.push('' + '\r\n');
        content.push(data + '\r\n');
    };

    content.push('--' + boundary + '--' + '\r\n');
    utils.dump(content);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, false);

    if (true) {
        /*
         * Heck, try making the whole thing a Blob to avoid string conversions
         */
        body = new Blob(content, {type: "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary});
        utils.dump(body);
    } else {
        /*
         * this didn't work either, but both work perfectly for sendMessage
         */
        body = content.join('');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
//        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
    }

    xhr.send(body);
    casper.log(xhr.responseText, 'error');
};
```

Again, this is in a CASPERJS environment, not a nodejs environment, so I don't have things like fs.createReadableStream or the File() constructor.